# Need URL of the document inside document library folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need URL of the document of document library.
Document library have many folders and The document may present in any folder.
So I need its URL to programatically download the document.

Comment: can you elaborate ? the question is not clear. Where do you want to get this url ?

Comment: using the object model or web services?

Answer (score 1):

```
SPFile yourFile = ...; // your way to ge the SPFile
var url = SPUtility.GetFullUrl(yourWeb, yourFile.Url);
```